# Webots to URDF Model Converter

Tags: ros, urdf, robot-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any existing work out there on a converter that allows generating URDF from Webots models? I´d be interested in anything useful for that task (also partial implementations, hints, etc.).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142391/webots-to-urdf-model-converter/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Webots now can export URDF files. You can right-click on a robot, click `Export`, and save it as `your_robot_name.urdf`. Or, you can use the `wb_robot_get_urdf` API function:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot#wb_robot_get_urdf

---

Originally posted by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) with karma: 486 on 2021-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There is no such tool to my knowledge. We recently developed a python script doing the reverse operation: converting a URDF file to a Webots PROTO file, I could share it with you if you are interested.

Please note however that most of the models provided within Webots are not licensed under a free open source license. Therefore, you are not allowed to redistribute modified or converted versions of these models, unless you get the official approval of the the copyright owner to do so (copyright owners of the models distributed in Webots include Cyberbotics and various companies and individuals). Please contact me if you have questions about a specific model.

Also, it may be interesting for you: the latest version of Webots, e.g., Webots 7.4.1, include a native generic ROS interface running in all versions of Webots, e.g., Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. This means that any robot in Webots can be connected to the ROS network out of the box, without installing or recompiling anything. See the documentation on Cyberbotics web site (google for ROS Webots).

Best regards,

-Olivier Michel
Cyberbotics Ltd., CEO

---

Originally posted by [Olivier Michel](https://answers.ros.org/users/13651/olivier-michel/) with karma: 31 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-03-24**:
Thanks Olivier! I´ll get back to you if it turns out the inverse operation would be useful. The model I have in mind is non-public/custom made, but licensing terms will of course always be followed.

**Comment by [lfrecalde1](https://answers.ros.org/users/65491/lfrecalde1/) on 2020-12-13**:
Hello, I have a problem when making the transformation of urdf webots, because when I use mobile robots on the wheels the colaiders become square and do not follow the shape of the wheel, which causes an unwanted movement in the robot, thanks

**Comment by [Olivier Michel](https://answers.ros.org/users/13651/olivier-michel/) on 2020-12-14**:
What are you trying to do? Convert a URDF model to a Webots PROTO using [webots2urdf](https://github.com/cyberbotics/urdf2webots) and use it in Webots? If so, could you please open an [issue](https://github.com/cyberbotics/urdf2webots/issues/new) and provide all the details, including files, allowing us to reproduce the problem and hopefully fix it.